# How to subscribe to multiple MQTT topics using the paho.mqtt.golang library?

Tags: go, mqtt, paho

I try to connect to a MQTT broker running on an external server where I need to handle multiple different topics. The problem is, that **only the last subscribed handler is called**, even if the topic does not match the one passed as parameter to the `Subscribe()` method.

**Example:**
sending any content to `p1/test` triggers the registrationHandler which only should listen for "*P1/controller/registration*". The other handlers or the DefaultPublishHandler are never called.

A simplified version of my program:

```
func main(){
    var opts = MQTT.NewClientOptions()
    opts.AddBroker(address)
    opts.SetClientID("go-controller")

    opts.SetDefaultPublishHandler(func(client MQTT.Client, msg MQTT.Message) {
        log.Printf("topic: %s\n", msg.Topic())
    })

    client = MQTT.NewClient(opts)
    if token := client.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        log.Panicln(token.Error())
    }

    client.Subscribe("P1/#", 0, logHandler)
    client.Subscribe("P1/controller/registration", 0, registrationHandler)
}

var logHandler MQTT.MessageHandler = func(client MQTT.Client, msg MQTT.Message) {
    ...
    log.Printf("Topic %s logged...\n", msg.Topic())
}

var registrationHandler MQTT.MessageHandler = func(client MQTT.Client, msg MQTT.Message) {
    ...
    log.Printf("Topic %s registered...\n", message.Value)
}
```

**EDIT #1**

I found out that the oder of subscribing to topics matters. When I swap both subscription calls the correct handlers get called.

Comment: You should probably raise that as bug. The client should probably apply all matching topics, not stop when it finds the first match

Comment: Either they have fixed this or I'm using a different version of Mosquitto, because this works for me regardless of the order of the subscription.

Answer (score -1):

For paho.mqtt.python implementation one client can subscribe to multiple subscriptions one call in an Array like so

```
client.subscribe([("P1/#", 0),("P1/controller/registration", 0)])
```

It is not sensitive to the order of items in the Array. This is not related to the 'golang' language implementation but I leave it here for reference sake.

Comment: I'm sure that this is not the case. When you visit the implementation (https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/master/client.go#L550) you see that it only allows one topic.

Comment: My mistake. I was referencing [https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python].  It supports this syntax and is not sensitive to order.